# Is a manually assigned address overwritten by the compiler? (Please see code as well)

Tags: c, memory-management

Some interesting bugs pop up when I run this code... Inside the input loop, things seem fine (not really, addresses aren't working properly but hey! *c atleast gives me the right value)

However in the output loop, things get messy. Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a;
    int count = 1, flag = 0;
    unsigned long int f = (unsigned long int)&a;
    do
    {
        char *c = (char*)(f+count);
        char temp = getchar();
        if (temp == '\n')
        {
            flag = 1;
            *c = '\0';
        }
        else
            *c = temp;
        printf("%p %c\n", c, *c);
        count++;
    }
    while( flag == 0);

    count = 0;
    char *h = (char *)f+1;
    do
    {
        printf("%p\n", (h+count));
        count++;
    } while (count < 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&a + 1` (the first `f + count`) already points at nothing, since `a` is a single character. Dereferencing it with `*c` is not allowed. Did you mean to make room for a whole string?

Comment: And you aren't manually assigning any addresses at all.

Comment: yes, I did... would initializing a to a dummy help?

Comment: It is one large UB.

Comment: char *h = (char *)f+1 is what I was referring to.. did I phrase it wrong?

Comment: Those are pointers which will have addresses assigned to them by the compiler. You have no hand in that.

Comment: pointer punning is not good

Comment: Initializing it wouldn’t help. Changing from a single character to an appropriately-sized character array would, but that wouldn’t make this code a good idea. If you’re trying to read a line, I recommend looking up examples of `fgets`.

Comment: `unsigned long int f = (unsigned long int)&a;`? `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer value.  You'd better not be running on 64-bit Windows, because `long` values are only 32 bits on Windows even in 64-bit mode.   Use `uintptr_t` if you want to hack addresses like this.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?  Why are you trying to store a sequence of characters to an object that can only hold a single character?  Why are you going through all the casting gymnastics instead of declaring `f` as a `char *`?  Why are you starting at index 1 instead of index 0?

Comment: regarding: `char temp = getchar();`   The function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want mean - you want to store string in the object of other type

```
char *getStringToAnotherType(FILE *fp, void *mydata, size_t sizeofMyData)
{
    return fgets(mydata, sizeofMyData, fp);
}

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    double y;
    char *str = getStringToAnotherType(stdin, &x, sizeof(x));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", str);

    str = getStringToAnotherType(stdin, &y, sizeof(y));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", str);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TGmnX7

Answer (score 2):

Not "addresses are not working", you are misusing the language.

It seem you need to learn about C memory concepts.

Here you have a single `char a` but you want to write there possibly many chars... By accessing it through a pointer, then incrementing the pointer you enter into some memory addresses you are not meant to touch.

Have a look at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/getchar